# BitmapImage.UriSource howto

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to add the background image of a control from code behind. Namely, I wrote the following:

```
    BitmapImage tmp = new BitmapImage();
    tmp.BeginInit();
    tmp.UriSource = new Uri(@"../images/card.png", UriKind.Relative);
    tmp.DecodePixelWidth = 240;
    tmp.EndInit();
    this.bg.Source = tmp;
```

The problem is that I am not able to get the Uri source right. The structure of the project is as follows: the images folder is at root level (say, at the same level of the Resources one) and card.png has its build action set to Resource and is always copied to the output folder. My class is in another folder, at the same level of the "images" one. What am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

i think problem is with your class location.... if your class is not there in root location then you have to use following code...

```
 new Uri(@"../images/card.png", UriKind.Relative)
```

Note: "../" may vary depending on your class location....

Comment: You are right; I'll edit my question. However, it did not work either.

Answer (score 2):

You can find a full list of the options in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx),
personally I prefer using these two **absolute** path formats:

For embedded resources (in current assembly):

```
"pack://application:,,,/Subfolder/ResourceFile.xaml"
```

For resources in installation folder:

```
"pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Subfolder/SOOFile.xaml"
```

See the [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx) for more options.

Comment: Sorry, no success yet. I am checking the link anyway.

Comment: @Tilvia a. When you select the png file in the Solution Explorer and check its Properties, what are the values of "Build Action" and of "Copy to Output Directory"? b. What is the assembly name of the assembly containing the control and what is that of the assembly containing the resource (png)? c. What is the path from the solution folder to each of the projects? d. What is the path to png within its project folder?

Answer (score 2):

I find many times that a full pack Uri is a bit much and that a simplified Uri works just as well if not better

```
Uri imageUri = new Uri("/namespace;component/images/card.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```